# Question about Formatting

Tags: formatting

I'm having difficulty formatting my Lab Report.

I've included a photo that basically shows the source and a preview of the document. How can I adjust the source code to place the new section on a new page while maintaining the order? Also when I added my photos, they all began to switch together. I guess that is because I no longer have them organized like a float - however, when I do use a float, the images appear in different sections.

The Code:

```
\pagebreak
\section{7.2 FET Current Source}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Lab10_Table2.png}[h]
\caption{This graph displays a table of the measured values R, \(V_{gs}\), \(I_{D}\), \(g_m = \Delta I_D / \Delta V_{GS}\) }
\end{figure}
\centering
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{7_2.png}
\caption{This graph displays a table of the measured values R, \(V_{gs}\), \(I_{D}\), \(g_m = \Delta I_D / \Delta V_{GS}\) }
\end{figure}
\pagebreak

\section{7.3 Source Follower}

\begin{center}
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{7_3.png}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{7_3R2Top.png}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that the floats are placed below rather than above the section header, you must change

```
\section{7.2 FET Current Source}
\begin{figure}
```

to

```
\section{7.2 FET Current Source}
\begin{figure}[h!]
```

Some additional comments:

- Do get rid of the almost-certainly-unwanted `\centering` instruction located *between* the first two floats.
- There's no point in running `\centering` inside a `center` environment (something that happens twice after the second `\section` directive).
- Please get rid of the `[h]` particle in `\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Lab10_Table2.png}[h]`.

Comment: My compliments +1.